# Can photons be converted to gluons

Tags: particle-physics, photons, standard-model, gluons

Is there any method we can use to convert a photon into a gluon, as they are similar in many respects. For instance, if we pass a $100\,{\rm keV}$ photon  through a strong electric field, can this photon convert into a gluon?

Comment: Not via any "real" process, but you can of course get virtual processes such as $\gamma \to q + \bar q \to g$

Comment: @Slereah You can draw that diagram, but it's color conservation violating, so that process is forbidden.

Answer (score 5):

The possible particle interactions in the standard model can be summarized with the vertices of Feynman diagrams:

[image]

Combining the top middle and top right vertex can give an interaction with a photon in, a quark "loop" and a gluon out. Gluons are [confined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon#Confinement), however, so you can't actually produce a free gluon this (or any other known) way.

Comment: well, you can get a gluon jet

Comment: This violates the conservation of color charge. You can produce two gluons, though.

Answer (score 4):

To illustrate @knzhou's comment to another answer:

A gluon is colored and a photon isn't, so that's out of the question. But two gluons can be in a color singlet, and, since you are sending a photon  into an electric field, it can interact with a [virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle) photon of that field to produce two gluons.  The process is $\gamma \gamma \to gg$, and the way it works is through either a virtual fermion box diagram, *or a virtual Higgs*!

So, then, modifying your question to an instructive one, yes, this rare process, time reversed, is behind the first observation of the Higgs. 
[image]

That is to say,  two gluons in colliding hadrons may (through quark loops), form a scalar Higgs field, which is neutral (and a color singlet). But, then, *very-very* rarely, through the intermediation of  (charged!) W bosons,
the Higgs can decay to two photons, possible to detect.

[image]

Some got extravagantly excited to see it happen: $gg\to h\to\gamma \gamma$.

Study of this process is [routine](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.181801).

Comment: Dear sir .you said that when photon be in electric field it interact with the virtual photon and produce two gluons. Does this production happens when any photon pass through an electric field? ?and what is the mean of "virtual photon "which you illustrate? ?

Comment: You might visualize the electric field as a collection of virtual photons. People do this type of experiment in searching for axions. BUT you must satisfy all kinematic (energy-momentum) constraints first... And the ensuing probability is fantastically small.... I hope you are not visualizing anything realistic.

Answer (score 1):

No. Gluons have color charge and photons do not. Since color is conserved, there is no process that can convert a single photon into a single gluon.